# Calculate all coordinates to x decimal places between two Lat/Long coordinates

Tags: php, math, gps, coordinates, geography

How can I calculate every Lat/Long coordinates between two Lat/Long coordinates in PHP?

Lets say I have coordinates A:

```
(39.126331, -84.113288)
```

and coordinates B:

```
(39.526331, -84.213288)
```

How would I calculate every possible coordinates between those two Lat/Long coordinates (in a direct line) up to five decimal places (e.g. 39.12633, -84.11328) and get list of coordinates between the two?

In addition, I have another set of coordinates (Coordinates C) that are slightly off and not on the track of coordinates between A and B.

How could I calculate the distance between coordinates C and the closest coordinates between A and B?

Comment: What do you mean by a "list" of coordinates.  Do you want every possible coordinate between the two, with 6 significant figures?  Or do you want the equation of a line between the two points?  Or do you want something else entirely?

Comment: Yes, every possible coordinate between the two, with 5 significant figures would suffice. I will clarify my question. Thanks.

Comment: It would help SO users if you included your end use and what you've already tried. Your calculation is going to yield an awfully big list of permutations. Why do you want to list them all when an algorithm would work better?

Comment: I'm trying to write a function or series of functions in PHP that will take a user's new set of GPS coordinates, their old set of coordinates, and a third set of coordinates unrelated to the user. The function basically needs to check to see if the third set or coordinates is close to the first or second set or any coordinates in-between the two.

Comment: Constructing a list of all possible coordinates between the two is an *incredibly* bad approach. Have you ever studied vectors?

Comment: [look at the Cross-track distance in this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), the example use js, but math is easily translated to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what solved this for me,

```
function point_to_line_segment_distance($startX,$startY, $endX,$endY, $pointX,$pointY)
{

        $r_numerator = ($pointX - $startX) * ($endX - $startX) + ($pointY - $startY) * ($endY - $startY);
        $r_denominator = ($endX - $startX) * ($endX - $startX) + ($endY - $startY) * ($endY - $startY);
        $r = $r_numerator / $r_denominator;

        $px = $startX + $r * ($endX - $startX);
        $py = $startY + $r * ($endY - $startY);

        $closest_point_on_segment_X = $px;
        $closest_point_on_segment_Y = $py;

        $distance = user_bomb_distance_calc($closest_point_on_segment_X, $closest_point_on_segment_Y, $pointX, $pointY);

        return array($distance, $closest_point_on_segment_X, $closest_point_on_segment_Y);
}

function user_bomb_distance_calc($uLat , $uLong , $bLat , $bLong)
{
    $earthRadius = 6371; #km
    $dLat = deg2rad((double)$bLat - (double) $uLat);
    $dlong = deg2rad((double)$bLong - (double) $uLong);

    $a = sin($dLat / 2 ) * sin($dLat / 2 ) + cos(deg2rad((double)$uLat)) * cos(deg2rad((double)$bLat)) * sin($dlong / 2) * sin($dlong / 2);


    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $distance = $earthRadius * $c;

    $meter = 1000; //convert to meter 1KM = 1000M

    return  intval( $distance * $meter ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a voronoi diagram from all the lat lon pairs and then look for adjacent cell. Also note that lat lon are angles and not world coordinate or cartesian coordinates. You can download my PHP class voronoi diagram @ phpclasses.org.